# Display JColorChooser as frame and pass color value to buttons

Tags: jcolorchooser

Hello All and Thanks in advance.

I need JColorChooser to appear as the top panel in my window. I used a button in its place for formatting purposes.(See picture) I also need to pass chosen color value from colorchooser to chosen button in array. I have most of the structure complete but I am still pretty new to Java.

** I would like to also note that I do not need 'ok' or 'cancel' buttons in the colorchooser dialog because once you select a color you should be able to press as many buttons as you would like to change their colors to selected color.

[View an image of my program](http://www.kolahoops.com/imgfiles/colorchooserhelp.png)

```
package main;


public class Main {
public static JPanel ToolPanel = new JPanel();  
public static JPanel GridPanel = new JPanel();// Define the Panel that Holds 256 Button Array
public static JPanel FullPanel  = new JPanel(); 
public static JButton button[] = new JButton[256];// Define button array for 256 buttons
private static JColorChooser colorChooser;  
public static JButton ColorChooserButton = new JButton("This is where the JColorChooser(colorChooser) should go. ");
public static JFrame MaineWindow = new JFrame("Kola Color Crapper");
final static String ToolPanelString = "Tool Panel";
final static String GridPanelString = "Grid Panel";


public static  ActionListener ButtonArrayActionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aef) {
      if (aef.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            ((JButton) aef.getSource()).setBackground(Color.blue);}}};

            public static  ActionListener ColorChooserButtonActionListener = new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aeef) {

                  String st="Welcome";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,st);

              }};




    public static void main( String[] args ){//Main (Run)
        // setup the gui with buttons
        CreateFullPanel();
        CreateMaineWindow();
}
//CreateToolPanel() is just used to test formatting
public static void CreateToolPanel(){
     ToolPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2));
 ToolPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
     ColorChooserButton.addActionListener(ColorChooserButtonActionListener);
     ToolPanel.add(ColorChooserButton);
      ColorChooserButton.setToolTipText("This is a tool tip.");
}

    public static void CreateFullPanel(){
CreateToolPanel();
CreateGridPanel();
//I want to insert CreateColorChooserPanel() where CreateToolPanel() is
//  CreateColorChooserPanel();

}


public static void CreateGridPanel() {
    GridPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2));
    GridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(16, 16, 0, 0));
    CreateButtonArray();// Create array of buttons

}

public static void CreateButtonArray(){
  for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1));
    button[i].addActionListener(ButtonArrayActionListener);
    GridPanel.add(button[i]);
    GridPanel.setToolTipText("ToolTIp does not work");
}
}

public static void CreateMaineWindow(){
    MaineWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));//Main Window is resizable
    MaineWindow.add(ToolPanel, ToolPanelString);
    MaineWindow.add(GridPanel, ToolPanelString);
    MaineWindow.setBounds(300,300,600,400);
    MaineWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    MaineWindow.pack();// pack all the contents of Main Window
    MaineWindow.setVisible(true);//Show Main Window
    }

public static void CreateColorChooserPanel(){

}

}
```

Comment: I would like to post the answer to this but the forum has a bunch of rules which restrict me from doing so............. LAME.

Comment: Note to self. If you get stumped or confused, EAT LUNCH and try again. No use thinking on an empty stomach.